# How to get list of all npm packages programatically

Tags: npm

I need to retrieve the whole list of npm packages pragmatically available on https://www.npmjs.com/. I know how to get the information of an individual package. e.g to get information of an express package I can use the following url "https://registry.npmjs.org/express" which will return all the information as JSON document.

Now kindly help me how can I get the information (names) of the whole list of packages?

Comment: Be aware that this isn't going to be a small list - there's currently nearly half a million packages on NPM.

Comment: @JoeClay Yes, I know that but how can I get the list? any idea?